# The remote server returned an unexpected response: (405) Method Not Allowed when .NET 4.7.2 WCF service is called from a .NET Core 3.1 REST API

Tags: c#, wcf, iis, rest

I have a WCF Service written for .NET Framework 4.7.2 at http://wcfservice.mydomain.com/service.svc

I also have a REST API written for .NET Core 3.1 at http://api.mydomain.com/

REST API has methods which act as transparent proxies which call WCF Service endpoints to fetch data. I have created the ServiceReference.cs in the REST API project via svcutil.

When I run the WCF Service both on Visual Studio 2019 and remote server IIS it works OK. No problems.

When I run these two projects on my local PC everything still seems OK. REST API works perfectly, calls data from WCF service and return response correctly. But when I move these two projects to the remote server IIS when I call the REST API it returns "The remote server returned an unexpected response: (405) Method Not Allowed" error.

Another strange thing is that for another project I use the same approach for a different REST API which works as a proxy to another WCF service hosted on the same remote server IIS, there is absolutely no problem and it works fine.

I have made some research and found no exact match for my case. Nobody faced this error while calling the WCF Service from a REST API. For the rest people mainly suggest two things : "Modification on Web.Config file" or "Adding WCF Activation".

First of all since I am using auto-generated code by svcutil I am not using a Web.config file which hold Service parameters and not sure to modify where and how.

Secondly, When I check the IIS I see that "HTTP activation" is already enabled under "WCF services" and I can not add "WCF HTTP Activation" under ".NET Framework 3.5". I face an error when I try to so.

Also I don't think these might be the solution because other projects on the IIS work well. I also checked application logs and Event Viewer logs but there is nothing helpful there.

I really appreciate a help on this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are these you projects running with the same application pool (settings) than the ones that work ? have you compared other settings of both ? any firewall/proxy could be involded that allows existing proyect to work but has not been configured for new one ?

Comment: What error are you facing when trying to add "WCF HTTP Activation" under ".NET Framework 3.5" ?

Comment: 405 means "there's a PUT available but you're trying to POST to it" (or any other combination of mismatched HTTP verbs).  [This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/testing-and-debugging/troubleshooting-http-405-errors-after-publishing-web-api-applications) is old but addresses some scenarios you might need to consider.

Comment: @MauricioGraciaGutierrez no they are running on separate Application pools. REST API runs on Unmanaged Code while WCF API runs on .NET 4. I don't think the firewall is an issue because other projects just run fine.

Comment: you mentioned another proyect that already works right ? that proyect has two application pools...correct ? is the current project application pools configured in a similiar way ?

Comment: @sellotape I have though on this but REST API is POST which WCF Service does not have such HTTP method attribute. The strange thing is that they work OK on my local PC while running Visual Studio 2019 with the same HTTP method.

Comment: @MauricioGraciaGutierrez yes they are all identical. Same architecture, same infrastructure, same settings. Possibly one small thing is not the same but unable to find it yet.

Comment: What error are you facing when trying to add "WCF HTTP Activation" under ".NET Framework 3.5" ?